# Render some views and 404 others in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

this is my routing-setup:

```
app.get('*', getJSON);

app.get('/', [list, render]);
app.get('/questions', [list, render]);
app.get('/ask', [ask, render]);

app.get('/:questionId(\\d+)', [question, render]);
app.get('/:questionId(\\d+)/:slug', [question, render]);

app.get('/sitemap.xml', clone);
app.get('/feed/qa.rss', clone);

app.post('/rest/1/:object/:method', [post, render]);
app.all('*', function(req, res){
    res.send(404).status('Page not found');
});
```

As you can see, almost all routes end with running a render-function. I would like to apply the same pattern as I'm using in the start with getJSON, but in the end. The simple way to do this would be to add

```
app.all('*', render);
```

at the end, but I cant, because I wish to skip sitemap.xml and qa.rss, and all paths not specified here, like `/foo`.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalhandler

as the last route.  I don't use express, but the express router

https://www.npmjs.com/package/router

The example there shows it using final handler

Comment: what should i do with sitemap.xml and qa.rss, regex exeption?

Comment: trap it and call next(err).  FinalHandler deals with it when its called

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware. Somelike this:

**/middlewares/error.js**

```
exports.notFound = function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);
  res.render('not-found'); // localized in /views/not-found.ejs or .html
};

// for regex error
exports.serverError = function(error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.render('server-error', {error: error});
};
```

Or:

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    if (err instanceof NotFound) {
        res.render('404.jade');
    } else if (err instanceof ServerError ){ // for regex error
        res.render('server-error.jade', {error: err});
    } else {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Documented in [Error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: what should i do with sitemap.xml and qa.rss, regex exeption?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a router for sitemap.xml or other files :

```
app.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res) {
  app.use( function (err, xml) {
      if (err) {
         res.status(400);
         res.render('404.jade');
      } 
  });
```

Keep your file name in array and call it at once.